# Not updating whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp

My Nokia Lumia 520 has stopped downloading or updating apps any more and I can't read my whatsapp messages. Whenever I try to update it it says error and some numbers please help

Comment: would you care to tell us what "numbers" you're seeing?

Comment: Those some numbers are the error code. You could find a solution with that code only. So please consider posting it.